# Export gridview to excel with frozen columns

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

How can I export my gridview to excel and have row and column frozen in excel?
Thanks!

Comment: what's your meaning about row and column frozen?

Comment: Once the data is in Excel, I wish to have cell B5 frozen. So row 1 to 5 are frozen and column A to B are frozen.Maybe I should export my gridview to an existing Excel template, but then, I do not know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

i hope it will help you
http://csharpektroncmssql.blogspot.com/2011/12/export-gridview-to-excel-in-aspnet.html